# Does setInterval() require different function names?

Tags: javascript

When learning Vue, I created two timers updating component data. When copy/pasting, I did not change, by mistake, the name of the second function in `setInterval()` but the code runs correctly nevertheless (the Vue part is not relevant, I keep it to have a functioning example but the core of my question is about the timers at the bottom of the code):

```js
var data_mynumber = {
  time: 1
};

Vue.component('mynumber', {
  template: '<div>time is {{time}}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return data_mynumber;
  }
})

var data_smthg = {
  time: 5
};

Vue.component('smthg', {
  template: '<div>hello {{time}}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return data_smthg;
  }
})


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root'
})

setInterval(
  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    data_mynumber.time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  },
  1000
);

setInterval(
  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    data_smthg.time = d;
  },
  100
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.5/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <mynumber></mynumber>
  <smthg></smthg>
</div>
```

Both `setInterval()` call the same function name `myTimer()`, each of them being different. The code runs as expected: the timers have a different tempo.

**Is this working by chance or can I reuse the same function name across all my `setInterval()` calls?**

Comment: Do you need a function name at all?  You are creating an anonymous callback.

Comment: @DavinTryon: I did not know that this was possible. I updated the accepted answer with the actual code in case someone is looking for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As matter of fact you don't need the name of the function. It's called anonymous functions or lambdas and doesn't make difference the name. You are passing it as a parameter, a callback. It won't call the name of the function, it will call the reference.

In the case of your code this would be

```
setInterval(
  function() {
    var d = new Date();
    data_mynumber.time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  },
  1000
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated your answer to add the relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

The function names have different scopes and therefore will not collide.

Although -- for debugging, it might be helpful to use different names.

Comment: To be specific, the scope of the name in a named function expression is the body of the function.